# python print line if contains word

Tags: python, database, search, error-handling

So im trying to let python search through my DataBase and then return the sentance where x is in
This is my code so far

```
word = input("")
x = open("Database.txt")
for line in x:
    if (word) in line:
        print(line)
    else:
        print("This start could not be found, maybe a typo, or try a different start!")
```

The error that i am getting when i type in a word that is in the DataBase.txt then it gives this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DataSearcher_DataBase2.py", line 1, in <module>
    word = input("")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'BrokenRunes' is not defined
```

And when i type in a word that is not in the DataBase.txt then it gives me this what i told it to do with the else: code but then for every line that its not detected in so i would like that to only happen once

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: I am using python version Python 3.8.0

Answer (score 0):

You want display the "not found" message only one time, so you need print it out of the `for`

There are a few minor corrections too

```
word = input("")
found = False
x = open("Database.txt")
for line in x.readlines():
    if word in line:
        print(line)
        found = True

if not found:
    print("This start could not be found, maybe a typo, or try a different start!")
```